# sharepoint 2013 workflows start on date

Tags: designer-workflow, timer-jobs

I have a requirement of starting a specific alert to user at the beginning of the month, can I do that with SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow? Was it changed from 2010, in 2010 we could not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2010 or 2013, you could create a workflow that pauses until a specific date and then resumes to send your alert.  You can add an item to a list and the workflow kicks off.  Then it pauses until the date you want, sends the email, and then pauses again until the next date.  That's about all you can do with a SharePoint Designer workflow for this.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't want to have multiple workflows all pausing, I just want something like timer job, but easily implemented like wf. I guess I will have to just use timer job.

Comment: Yea, a workflow cannot have a "scheduled" start.  So, a timer job is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a workflow using PowerShell script and scheduled this script,using windows task scheduler to run in your own way.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dffdceab-f2fe-4886-8e2a-ea26cf08c78a/how-to-start-a-speific-workflow-programatically-in-sharepoint-2010-via-powershell

$siteURL="http://servername:5555/"

$listName="Test"

$site=Get-Spsite $siteURL

$web=$site.RootWeb

$list=$web.Lists[$listName]

$item=$list.Items[0]

$manager=$site.WorkFlowManager

$association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations[0]

$data=$association.AssociationData

$wf=$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data,$true)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharePoint Workflow Scheduler](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/) developed by my team.

It supports quite complex schedules. You can create site level workflow and schedule it to start periodically.

See documentation:

- [How to schedule SharePoint workflow](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/docs/schedule-workflow/)
- [How to create advanced schedule using *cron* syntax](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/docs/advanced-schedule-cron-syntax/)

**Note:** It is paid, but quite cheap tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it client side.  Use JQuery in a CEWP to check the date.  If the date = the first of the month, update a field in the list to track it and have your workflow check for the flag when an item is modified.  This will keep you from having to worry about pause timer services which can get messy if there are a bunch of them.  Should not be too hard to code either.  Bad thing is, you have to make sure you at least visit the page on the 1st to run the document ready :).